# the best way to have separate stylesheets for different actions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one app layout that includes app wide css stylesheets and js files, but some controller's actions need additional stylesheets that is used only for these action
s view? What is the best way to include them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your app is typically something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' -%>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'yui', 'application' -%>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield -%>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can add other yield blocks wherever you like, named whatever you want. Typically I used this to include page-specific functionality wherever I like, even to the degree that maybe partials supply their own.

```
# layouts/application.html.erb
<html>
  <head>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' -%>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'yui', 'application' -%>
    <%= yield :head -%>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield -%>
  </body>
</html>

# views/profiles/show.html.erb
<%= title("#{@user.name}'s Profile") -%>

<% content_for :head do -%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'gallery' %>
<% end %>

<%= render @user.photos %>
```

So on and so forth...

Comment: Then how do you stop the application stylesheet manifest from including all the different controller sheets / other sheets in the assets directory from being compiled together?

Answer (score 0):

For the javascript, one way to deal with this is using a <%= yield :javascript %> inside your the ... tag in your layout file. Then in your view code, you can use a <% content_for :javascript do %> ...put your javascript here ... <% end %>

This way, your javascript and your html erb code live in the same location.

Javascript that is used throughout the sight can be placed in a global file.